# BitmapFactory returns difference sizes of Bitmap from drawable and from file

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have two copies of same image. One of them is inside the resource folder (default drawable) of the app and the other one is on the external storage.

I get the `Bitmap` with the following codes:

```
 // Get from storage
 BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());

 // Get from resource
 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

However, they result in different sizes in `ImageView` with `wrap_content` in height and width. How can I solve this?

Comment: `decodeResource()` may take screen density into account. `decodeFile()` almost certainly does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think so and I am searching the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is because of the implementation of `BitmapFactory`. During the call in `decodeResourceStream` from `decodeResource`, it will assign a `BitmapFactory.Options` wtih `inDensity` set to `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT` if `BitmapFactory.Options` is null.

On the other hand, `decodeFile` is passed through `setDensityFromOptions` which return immediately if `BitmapFactory.Options` is null.

Therefore, one of the solutions is to scale the density of `decodeFile` by the following code.

```
BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
option.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), option);
```

If you want to do it in reverse, you can use the following code.

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

Notice that there will be "Constants and Resource Type Mismatches", but it can still be compiled. `decodeResource` also call `openRawResource` as `InputStream`, so this is fine.